# Fail with basic usage of haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm learning Haskell and trying to setup my Emacs development environment (reading [this](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md)).
One of things I should do is to install `hindent`.
Recommended method [here](https://github.com/chrisdone/hindent#install) is just `stack install hindent`. I guess it should be installed in stack's `global-project` space. My global stack yaml at `$HOME/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` is:

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages: []
extra-deps: []
resolver: ghc-7.10.3
```

I don't use any system `ghc` (there is no `ghc` or `ghci` on my `$PATH`).
On `stack install hindent` it adviced me to extend `extra-deps`:

```
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: ghc-7.10.3 from implicit global project's config file: /home/me/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml

While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for hindent-5.2.1:
    descriptive must match >=0.7 && <0.10, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                (latest applicable is 0.9.4)
    exceptions must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.8.3)
    haskell-src-exts must match >=1.18, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                     (latest applicable is 1.18.2)
    monad-loops must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.4.3)
    mtl must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 2.2.1)
    path must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.5.9)
    path-io must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 1.2.0)
    text must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 1.2.2.1)
    unix-compat must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.4.2.0)
    utf8-string must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 1.0.1.1)
    yaml must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.8.20)

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/me/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:
- descriptive-0.9.4
- exceptions-0.8.3
- haskell-src-exts-1.18.2
- monad-loops-0.4.3
- mtl-2.2.1
- path-0.5.9
- path-io-1.2.0
- text-1.2.2.1
- unix-compat-0.4.2.0
- utf8-string-1.0.1.1
- yaml-0.8.20
```

When I do what is proposed it suggests some new dependencies (which are probably dependencies of those which are added before) etc. At the end it results in situatuation where some two dependencies have unmet versions.

I presume that something is wrong with my configuration (or understanding of stack) since I think that obtaining implicit dependencies is job of a build tool.

Does someone more experienced can infer what is my beginner fault?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the resolver in your global project is `ghc-7.10.3`? (I think that may be the source of your issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not generally recommended to use a ghc version as a resolver, for the reason you've discovered: you need to manually specify lots of package versions. Instead, I'd recommend switching to lts-6.23, or something else similar.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense but a bit different than standard build tools in other ecosystems I've seen so far. `hindent` version that is installed through `lts-6.23` or even `lts-7.5` is version <5 but I need 5>. I've switched to nightly to get what I need. Is my reason correct according to stack philosophy or I should specify a particular version of single package (`hindent`) somewhere?

Comment: You can try specifying a version of hindent on the command line, but choosing a nightly snapshot with the desired version is a good call.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. If you just wanna get moving fast:

```
stack upgrade --git  && \
rm -rf ~/.stack      && \
stack setup          && \
stack install hindent
```

Why not use GHC 8.X and a fresh new Stack? ;)